# filtering an rdd based on presence of elements from an array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I have an rdd which has 50 million elements all of which are strings. I have to filter and make a new rdd which has any of the following terms:

```
val x = Array("apple", "mango", "papaya","pineapple")
```

SO, if a string in original rdd contains any of the string from above array, it should be in the filtered rdd.
What's the efficient way to do it in scala?
Is there an one line way of doing it or do I have to traverse through each element and find out?

Comment: I can't work out what you mean. What do you mean by an element being a document? Do you mean a String? What is a "rdd which has any of the following terms"? Do you mean "where the string" contains or more of these words? More details and more careful description, please

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul i have made edits. Kindly see.

Comment: I'm backing up @TheArchetypalPaul I can't get what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
val strings = Set("apple", "mango", "papaya",v"pineapple")
rdd.filter(strings.contains(_))
```